# Wamp not opening localhost on Windows 8

Tags: php, windows-8, localhost, wamp

Wamp is installed correctly and it works fine. However, when I try to open a file with Chrome (or any other) from the file explorer it opens the file with raw code: file:///C:/wamp/www/testing/built-in.php 
But when I manually change the URL to localhost/tesing/built-in.php then the php code is executed fine.

So my question is: is there a way to open a PHP file in "localhost" instead of the "file:///" directly from the file explorer?

Comment: Nope. You just have to type in the url.

Comment: How hard is it to type `localhost` in your browser and click on your script name? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WAMP is a server, therefore the files can only be executed whilst being called from the server rather than from the local drive. When opening from the local drive, the file "by-passes" the server and it is directly displayed via the browser.